# How to validate file size in javascript before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all, the question Title may be duplicated but the idea is different.

I need to validate file size in `html` using attribute 
like:

`<input type="file" id="file" multiple="" data-my-size="123456">`

When the user selects file it checks the size with this data-my-size value. 
and then it creates a div inside a `div` with id "`file-list`" with file name and if it is allowed or not.

for example:

```
<div id="file-list">
 <div> File 123.png is allowed </div>
 <div> File 321.png is Not allowed </div>
</div>
```

and it works with more than One input in the same page

Answer (score 0):

Try this function....

```
 function GetFileSize(fileid) {
 try 
 {
     var fileSize = 0;
     //for IE
     if ($.browser.msie) {
        //before making an object of ActiveXObject, 
        //please make sure ActiveX is enabled in your IE browser
        var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); var filePath = $("#" + fileid)[0].value;
        var objFile = objFSO.getFile(filePath);
        var fileSize = objFile.size; //size in kb
        fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb 
     }
     //for FF, Safari, Opeara and Others
     else {
          fileSize = $("#" + fileid)[0].files[0].size //size in kb
          fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb 
     }
       alert("Uploaded File Size is" + fileSize + "MB");
 }
 catch (e) {
       alert("Error is :" + e);
 }
```